# Plotly: How to give different label names in a dropdown menu?

Tags: python, plotly

I was learning plotly dropdown menu and stumbled on a label problem.

## Question

- How to show labels `sin and sin-1` when selected Sine. And show labels `tan and tan-1` when selected Tan?

## MWE

```py
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y1b = y1-1

y2 = np.tan(x)
y2b = y2-1

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add one ore more traces
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,name='sin'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1b,name='sin - 1'))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,name='tan'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2b,name='tan - 1'))

# construct menus
updatemenus = [{'buttons': [{'method': 'update',
                             'label': 'Sine',
                             'args': [{'y': [y1, y1b]},]
                              },
                            {'method': 'update',
                             'label': 'Tan',
                             'args': [
                                 {'y': [y2, y2b],'label':['a','b']},
                             ]}
                           ],
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```

## output

[image]

Comment: The legend is controlled by `args: {'visible':[True, True, False, False]}`.The name of the legend is possible with `'name':['a','b']`, but it doesn't work when combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's a generic helper function that you could use:**

```py
# Helper functions to create the appropriate buttons
def makePlotButtons(options, nTracesPerOption=1):    
    buttons = []
    for i, opt in enumerate(options):
        visibleArr = np.full((nTracesPerOption*len(options),), 
                             False, dtype=bool)
        
        startIdx = nTracesPerOption*i
        for idx in range(nTracesPerOption):
            visibleArr[startIdx + idx] = True
            
        buttons.append(dict(label=str(opt),
                            method='restyle',
                            args=[{'visible': list(visibleArr)}]))    # 'Visible' arg determines which plots are shown 
                                                                      # depending on which dropdown is selected 
    return buttons
```

where `options` is a list of strings and `nTracesPerOption` is how many traces you have per option. In the case of your questions, your `options` parameter would be `['Sine', 'Tan']` and `nTracesPerOption` is 2 (e.g. for sin and sin - 1).

**Then in the MWE you provided, you would update the** `buttons` **field in your** `updatemenus` **variable to** `makePlotButtons(options, 2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helper function. But This has the same problem. I tried the code and got this same output: https://i.imgur.com/rwMwhpp.png

Comment: I got it. For first time it shows wrong outputs, but when I click dropdown menu multiple time, it works good. Thanks a lot for helper function.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my answer, my apologies. I think plotly by default turns on all traces so the current dropdown option is ignored. That's why I like to use `active = -1` as a parameter for the menu.

Answer (score 1):

For challenges such as this I've pretty much moved on to using Dash, so my abilites when it comes to specifying dropdown buttons like this is a bit rusty. So you'll have to forgive me because the following suggestion will only be a good solution if you stick to switching between `Sine` and `Tan` for the dropdown options. And select `Sine` as your *first* option. If you do, then:

#### 1. Clicking `Sine` will give you this:

[image]

#### 2. Clicking `Tan` will give you this:

[image]

#### 3. And clicking `Sine` for the second time will give you this again:

[image]

#### And on and on it spins...

And notice how the legend shows only traces for your selected categories.
This has been made possible through specifying which traces to restyle by specifying them trough their position in `fig.data` using integers `[0, 1]` and `[2, 3]` for the different buttons. The toggle functionality has been made possible using the [args2](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/) attribute. You can see all details in the complete code snippet below.

#### So why is this not a perfect solution??

1. The button label shows some weire behavior where `Sine` disappears.
2. If you select `Tan` *first* then... Try for yourself and see =)

Anyway, if other options turn out to be too complex or have other shortcomings, maybe you or other readers figure out how to make this suggestion meet your requirements 100%.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y1b = y1-1

y2 = np.tan(x)
y2b = y2-1

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add one ore more traces
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,name='sin'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1b,name='sin - 1'))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,name='tan'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2b,name='tan - 1'))

# construct menus
updatemenus = [{'buttons': [{'method': 'restyle',
                             'label': 'Sine',
                             'args': [{'y': [y1, y1b],
                                       'label':'Sine',
                                       'name':['sin', 'sin - 1'],
                                       'visible': True}, [0, 1]],
                             'args2': [{'y': [y1, y1b],
                                       'visible': False}, [2, 3]]
                              },
                            
                            {'method': 'restyle',
                             'label': 'Tan',
                             'args': [{'y': [y2, y2b],
                                       'name': ['tan', 'tan - 1'],
                                       'visible':True}, [0, 1]],
                             'args2': [{'y': [y2, y2b],
                                       'visible':False}, [2, 3]],
                             }
                           ],
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following answer as suggested by @Jacob K

```py
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)


# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.sin(x),name='sin'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.sin(x)-1,name='sin - 1'))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.cos(x),name='cos'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.cos(x)-1,name='cos - 1'))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.tan(x),name='tan'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=np.tan(x)-1,name='tan - 1'))

# construct menus
# Helper functions to create the appropriate buttons
def makePlotButtons(options, nTracesPerOption=1):    
    buttons = []
    for i, opt in enumerate(options):
        visibleArr = np.full((nTracesPerOption*len(options),), 
                             False, dtype=bool)
        
        startIdx = nTracesPerOption*i
        for idx in range(nTracesPerOption):
            visibleArr[startIdx + idx] = True
            
        buttons.append(dict(label=str(opt),
                            method='restyle',
                            args=[{'visible': list(visibleArr)}]))    # 'Visible' arg determines which plots are shown 
                                                                      # depending on which dropdown is selected 
    return buttons

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
updatemenus = [{'buttons': makePlotButtons(['Sine','Cosine', 'Tan'], 2),
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]


fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```

and got following output
[image]