# Use button to filter different data in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I followed the answer from @PythononToast [How can I add a button or dropdown in a plot created using Plotly in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710352/how-can-i-add-a-button-or-dropdown-in-a-plot-created-using-plotly-in-python/65710995#65710995) The plot first generated is correct, but values changed after clicking the drop-down filter. As we can see from the plot he generated was not correct. May I know the reason?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Dummy data
df_germany = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[200,250],'Gas':[400,500]})
df_poland = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[500,150],'Gas':[600,100]})
df_spain = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[700,260],'Gas':[900,400]})

#put dataframes into object for easy access:
df_dict = {'Germany': df_germany, 
           'Poland': df_poland, 
           'Spain': df_spain}

#create a figure from the graph objects (not plotly express) library
fig = go.Figure()

buttons = []
i = 0

#iterate through dataframes in dict
for country, df in df_dict.items():
    #iterate through columns in dataframe (not including the year column)
    for column in df.drop(columns=['Fuels']):
        #add a bar trace to the figure for the country we are on
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                          name = column,
                          #x axis is "fuels" where dates are stored as per example
                          x = df.Fuels.to_list(),
                          #y axis is the data for the column we are on
                          y = df[column].to_list(),
                          #setting only the first country to be visible as default
                          visible = (i==0)
                        )
                     )
        
    #args is a list of booleans that tells the buttons which trace to show on click
    args = [False] * len(df_dict)
    args[i] = True
    
    #create a button object for the country we are on
    button = dict(label = country,
                  method = "update",
                  args=[{"visible": args}])
    
    #add the button to our list of buttons
    buttons.append(button)
    
    #i is an iterable used to tell our "args" list which value to set to True
    i+=1
        
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
        #change this to "buttons" for individual buttons
        type="dropdown",
        #this can be "left" or "right" as you like
        direction="down",
        #(1,1) refers to the top right corner of the plot
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        #the list of buttons we created earlier
        buttons = buttons)
    ],
    #stacked bar chart specified here
    barmode = "stack",
    #so the x axis increments once per year
    xaxis = dict(dtick = 1))

fig.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of this issue is that the code does not create the `buttons` list correctly. If you print this list after it is created, you will get the following:

```
[{'label': 'Germany', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [True, False, False]}]},
 {'label': 'Poland', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [False, True, False]}]},
 {'label': 'Spain', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [False, False, True]}]}]
```

Each list corresponding to the key `'visible'` indicates which traces should be shown in the plot when a country is selected. The problem is that the nested `for` loops create a total of 6 traces: one each for gas and coal data for every country. Thus the list assigned to `'visible'` should consist of 6 boolean values: for a given country it should have two `True` values, corresponding to gas and coal traces for this country. In other words, the `buttons` list should look as follows:

```
[{'label': 'Germany', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [True, True, False, False, False, False]}]},
 {'label': 'Poland', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [False, False, True, True, False, False]}]},
 {'label': 'Spain', 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [False, False, False, False, True, True]}]}]
```

Below is the code modified to fix this. It changes only the way the `args` list is created inside the outer `for` loop, since this is the list that gets assigned to `'visible'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Dummy data
df_germany = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[200,250],'Gas':[400,500]})
df_poland = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[500,150],'Gas':[600,100]})
df_spain = pd.DataFrame({'Fuels':[2010,2011],'Coal':[700,260],'Gas':[900,400]})

#put dataframes into object for easy access:
df_dict = {'Germany': df_germany, 
           'Poland': df_poland, 
           'Spain': df_spain}

#create a figure from the graph objects (not plotly express) library
fig = go.Figure()

buttons = []
i = 0

n_cols = len(df_germany.columns) - 1

#iterate through dataframes in dict
for country, df in df_dict.items():

    #iterate through columns in dataframe (not including the year column)
    for column in df.drop(columns=['Fuels']):
        #add a bar trace to the figure for the country we are on
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                          name = column,
                          #x axis is "fuels" where dates are stored as per example
                          x = df.Fuels.to_list(),
                          #y axis is the data for the column we are on
                          y = df[column].to_list(),
                          #setting only the first country to be visible as default
                          visible = (i==0)
                        )
                     )
        
    #args is a list of booleans that tells the buttons which trace to show on click
    args = [False] * len(df_dict)*(n_cols)
    args[i*n_cols:(i+1)*n_cols] = [True]*n_cols
    
    #create a button object for the country we are on
    button = dict(label = country,
                  method = "update",
                  args=[{"visible": args}])
    
    #add the button to our list of buttons
    buttons.append(button)
    
    #i is an iterable used to tell our "args" list which value to set to True
    i+=1
        
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
        #change this to "buttons" for individual buttons
        type="dropdown",
        #this can be "left" or "right" as you like
        direction="down",
        #(1,1) refers to the top right corner of the plot
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        #the list of buttons we created earlier
        buttons = buttons)
    ],
    #stacked bar chart specified here
    barmode = "stack",
    #so the x axis increments once per year
    xaxis = dict(dtick = 1))

fig.show()
```