# How to set the values of args and args2 in Plotly's buttons in updatemenus?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm new to plotly and I am trying to understand how to set the values for args and args2 in the updatemenus functionality offered by plotly (as explained in the documentation [Updatemenus documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/#layout-updatemenus-buttons-method)).

I tried to play with a code snippet I found in an answer here in stackoverflow ([Plotly: How to give different label names in a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605076/plotly-how-to-give-different-label-names-in-a-dropdown-menu/65621894#65621894)).

Here's the modified code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y1b = y1-1

y2 = np.tan(x)
y2b = y2-1

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add one ore more traces
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,name='sin', visible=False, showlegend=True))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1b,name='sin - 1', visible=False, showlegend=True))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,name='tan', visible=False, showlegend=True))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2b,name='tan - 1', visible=False, showlegend=True))

# construct menus
updatemenus = [{'active':-1,'buttons': [{'method': 'restyle',
                             'label': 'Sine',
                             'args': [{'y': [y1, y1b, y2, y2b],
                                       'label':'Sine',
                                       'name':['sin', 'sin - 1', 'tan', 'tan - 1'],
                                       'visible': True}, [0, 1]],
                             'args2': [
                                       {'visible': False}, ]
                              },
                            
                            {'method': 'restyle',
                             'label': 'Tan',
                             'args': [{'y': [y2, y2b, y1, y1b],
                                       'name':['tan', 'tan - 1', 'sin', 'sin - 1'],
                                       'visible':True}, [0, 1]],
                             'args2': [{
                                       'visible':False},  
                                      ],
                             }
                           ],
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```

This gives me what I wanted to achieve that is to display the sine plots when I first click on Sine in the dropdown menu and clear the plot when I click again on Sine (and the same for Tan).

However, my problems are :

- I can't find any information in the documentation or anywhere else on what to pass to args and args2. Could you please provide any reference to documentation ?
- At the end, I'm not even sure how to understand the behavior of args especially the first item (dictionary with 'y' and 'name' keys) and the second item with what I understand is a list of trace indices (?). In the following example, I set the list of indices to [2, 3] in the both Sine and Tan buttons. Therefore, I expect to have Tan plots by clicking on the Sine buttons and vice versa for the other button. But the plots do not change.

```
    # construct menus
    updatemenus = [{'active':-1,'buttons': [{'method': 'restyle',
                                 'label': 'Sine',
                                 'args': [{'y': [y1, y1b, y2, y2b],
                                           'label':'Sine',
                                           'name':['sin', 'sin - 1', 'tan', 'tan - 1'],
                                           'visible': True}, [2, 3]],
                                 'args2': [
                                           {'visible': False}, ]
                                  },
    
                                {'method': 'restyle',
                                 'label': 'Tan',
                                 'args': [{'y': [y2, y2b, y1, y1b],
                                           'name':['tan', 'tan - 1', 'sin', 'sin - 1'],
                                           'visible':True}, [2, 3]],
                                 'args2': [{
                                           'visible':False},  
                                          ],
                                 }
                               ],
                    'direction': 'down',
                    'showactive': True,}]
```

Could you please show me the correct way to set these values to target the right trace ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can pass any layout param to the args param: title, yaxis, hovermode, autosize, etc.

Comment: Thank your for your answer ! I tried the layout params but this did not work. I could figure out that args accepts trace parameters (those we pass to fig.update_trace()). See [link](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/).

Still, I don't see why the plot is not updated with the correct trace. Any help on this part ? Thanks again

Comment: @Downforu Did my explanation make sense to you?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer ! it totally makes sense now !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### 1. Documentation

You can find info on `args` and `args2`  under [`buttons`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/#layout-updatemenus-items-updatemenu-buttons) for [`updatemenus`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/):

> args Parent: layout.updatemenus[].buttons[] Type: list Sets the
> arguments values to be passed to the Plotly method set in `method` on
> click.
>
> args2 Parent: layout.updatemenus[].buttons[] Type: list Sets a 2nd set
> of `args`, these arguments values are passed to the Plotly method set
> in `method` when clicking this button while in the active state. Use
> this to create toggle buttons.

Admittedly, this is easier to find than to fully comprehend. The thing you should focus on first is `Use this to create toggle buttons`. Because that's exactly what `args2` is for; to provide a set of arguments that are set when a button is `"not clicked"`. So `buttons` have several parameters:

1. `args`: what happens when the button is clicked
2. `args2`: what happens when it’s unclicked (to create toggle buttons)
3. `label`: what is written on the button / label
4. `method`: whether the button changes the plot, the layout or both

#### 2. The correct way to set things up

The complete snippet below will show you how you can take the example that you've been running test on, and produce a figure that toggles between showing `sine` and `tangent` values for a few series.

#### Plot1 -  Click button to get:

[image]

#### Plot 2 - Click button again to get:

[image]

If you take a closer look at the code below, you can see that I've set it up exactly as described in the documentation:

The first dict in `args` and `args2` handles changes made to the traces / data:

```
{'y': [y1, y1b],
'name':['sin', 'sin - 1'],
'visible': True},
```

The second dict handles changes made to the layout of the figure:

```
{'title':'Sine'}
```

In the example below, it's possible to edit both data and layout since `method` has been set to `update`.

The third element, a list, determines which traces changes should be made for:

```
[0, 1]
```

#### And one more important thing

What seemed to trigger the question [Plotly: How to give different label names in a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605076/plotly-how-to-give-different-label-names-in-a-dropdown-menu/65621894#65621894) is the fact that the `label` property of the `button` can't be edited through the parameters in `arg`, and thus the functionality of the `button`, since both `label` and `arg` are exactly that; parameters of the button and not the ***`figure object`*** that the button controls. This becomes more apparent if you change the `type` attribute from `button` to dropdown. Now you can see that you'll lose the label when the button is "unclicked" / dropdown option is unselected:

#### Plot 3:

[image]

And the only way to handle this is through adding another button if you'd like to emulate a toggle functionality for the button label, since the parameters in `args` or `args2` are unable to "reach" that particular attribute of the button. I ***really*** hope someone is willing to prove me wrong on this one though, because these things often suddenly leave me a bit confused. But I hope that I've been able to make things a bit *less* confusing for you at least.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y1b = y1-1

y2 = np.tan(x)
y2b = y2-1

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add one ore more traces
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,name='sin', visible=True, showlegend=True))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1b,name='sin - 1', visible=True, showlegend=True))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,name='tan', visible=False, showlegend=True))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2b,name='tan - 1', visible=False, showlegend=True))
fig.update_layout({'title' : 'Sine'})

# construct menus
updatemenus = [{
#                 'active':1,
                'buttons': [{'method': 'update',
                             'label': 'Toggle Sine / Tangent',
                             'args': [
                                      # 1. updates to the traces
                                      {'y': [y1, y1b],
                                       'name':['sin', 'sin - 1'],
                                       'visible': True}, 
                                      
                                      # 2. updates to the layout
                                      {'title':'Sine'},
                                      
                                      # 3. which traces are affected 
                                      [0, 1],
                                      
                                      ],
                             'args2': [
                                       # 1. updates to the traces  
                                       {'y': [y2, y2b],
                                       'name':['tan', 'tan - 1'],
                                       'visible':True},
                                      
                                       # 2. updates to the layout
                                       {'title':'Tangent'},
                                       
                                       # 3. which traces are affected
                                       [0, 1]
                                      ]
                              },
                            ],
                'type':'buttons',
#                 'type':'dropdown',
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```